# Option thref of package ntheorem causes equation numbering problem with amsmath's split environment

Tags: numbering, amsthm, ntheorem

See the MWE first:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[amsmath, thref]{ntheorem}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
a & b\\
c & d
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

And the result of the MWE:

http://i4.tietuku.com/52b556e219f94a84.png

It could be clearly seen that the numbering of equation is troubled with the `thref` option of the `ntheorem` package. Removing the `thref` option or using the `aligned` (sub-)environment instead of the `split` (sub-)environment could bypass this problem.

Is this a bug of the `ntheorem` package, and how to fix this problem?

Environment information:

- TeX Live 2015
- Mac OS X, 10.9.5
- Package used are listed below:

File List:

```
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 amsmath.sty    2013/01/14 v2.14 AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d
  amsopn.sty    1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names
ntheorem.sty    2011/08/15 1.33
  ifthen.sty    2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
```

Comment: Looks like a bug. Same problem with MiKTeX 2.9, Windows 7.

Comment: There is no problem, if you don't use this option and replace it with the `cleveref` package, which anyway supersedes the option (and much more!).